# Symfony/Doctrine keeps creating the same migration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, database-migration

<sup>*Edit: Turns out other projects on the same machine are having the same issue. The question is for one specific project:*</sup>

I have a Symfony4 project in which I have a few entities (created via `make:entity`). I just noticed that the last 4 migrations have the exact same query in them (and yes, I run migrations in between). Example:

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE event CHANGE visible_from visible_from DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE visible_till visible_till DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE max_signups max_signups INT DEFAULT NULL');
```

I ran that query manually and that actually updated the table. I then created a new migration to test: The above query was there, again.

I've cleared cache, ran `doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`, double checked for weird stuff, but everything is normal.

I have the same 3 queries every time and they all have one thing in common: They have nullable=true. All other entities do not have nullable=true in them.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $maxSignups;
```

The downmigration might be a hint:

```
ALTER TABLE event CHANGE visible_from visible_from DATETIME DEFAULT \'NULL\',
                                                  This I find odd---^
```

MariaDB version: 10.2.14
PHP: 7.2.4
symfony/orm-pack: "^1.0"

Anyone who knows why?

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3321#issuecomment-447642346 suggests ... you might have to set the correct mariadb version? (idea stolen from https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3006)

Comment: It says `driver: 'pdo_mysql'` and `server_version: '5.7'`, which is my mysql version. Not sure wether that should say mariaDB. My others projects dont have this problem, same environment

Comment: I stand corrected, my other projects are having the same issue. Only the nullable attributes

Answer (score 1):

I still dont really know why ( So I'll leave this question open for a bit), but this is what I did:

I was running both MySQL and MariaDB and it defaulted to MySQL. Turned that off, switched to MariaDB and adding a version in doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.2.14'
```

It doesnt really care about the version though. I made a typo and wrote `12.2.14` and it worked absolutally fine. I'm guessing it has a `version>$n` check somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained here: 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/9547#issue-179389686

The most important is setting server_version with prefix "mariadb", the MariaDB version is less important.

Alternatively, you may not set server_version at all, then it should be detected automatically.

Below is the DBAL driver function responsible for parsing server_version:

```
public function createDatabasePlatformForVersion($version)
{
    $mariadb = false !== stripos($version, 'mariadb');
    if ($mariadb && version_compare($this->getMariaDbMysqlVersionNumber($version), '10.2.7', '>=')) {
        return new MariaDb1027Platform();
    }

    if ( ! $mariadb && version_compare($this->getOracleMysqlVersionNumber($version), '5.7.9', '>=')) {
        return new MySQL57Platform();
    }

    return $this->getDatabasePlatform();
}
```

And here is the link to the whole class: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/f76bf5ef631cec551a86c2291fc749534febebf1/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php#L133